# Regex Remove Everythings After Nth Slash

Tags: regex, re2

actually with this regex i want to group prometheus metric by label (http_path). I need to remove everything after nth slash and also remove query params with regex (RE2).

Let say i have these paths and need to remove everything after 2nd slash:

```
/a
/a/b/c
/a/b
/a/b/
/a?query=true
/a/b/c?query=true
```

expected result:

```
/a
/a/b
/a/b
/a/b
/
```

**First workaround:**

`(^/(?:[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?){0,2})`

I don't know why sometimes it become weird on prometheus. For instance, i have path like this:

```
/a%
```

regex must be match with `/a`, but in prometheus it's become like no match at all.

**Second work arround**:

`(.*?/.*?){0,2}/.*`

It will not capture `/a`

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe `^(?:/[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){0,2}/?` will help? With a capturing group: `^((?:/[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){0,2}/?)`